# How to do integration tests on Firebase Functions using local emulator?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I successfully wrote some tests for my Firebase functions, however now I want to test functions that manipulate Firestore data.

to do so I execute the following

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="my-project-key.json"
export FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST="localhost:8080"
firebase emulators:start --import ./functions/test/fixture --project my-project
```

and then I run

`npm run test`

The test code is as follows:

```
const test = require("firebase-functions-test")()
const functions = require("../index")

describe("Tests", () => {

  it("Do test", async () => {
    const wrapped = test.wrap(functions.doTest)
    const result = await wrapped({id:"1"})
  })
})
```

The `index` file imported contains:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions")
const admin = require("firebase-admin")

admin.initializeApp()

exports.doTest = functions.https.onCall(async (data) => {
  const {id} = data
  const vehicleRef = admin.firestore().collection("vehicles").doc(id)
  const vehicle = await vehicleRef.get()
})
```

Yet every time I call a Firebase function that accesses Firestore I get the following error (in this case on `vehicleRef.get()`):

```
Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.
    at GoogleAuth.getApplicationDefaultAsync (/MyProject/firebase/functions/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:157:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
    at async GoogleAuth.getClient (/MyProject/firebase/functions/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:490:17)
    at async GrpcClient._getCredentials (/MyProject/firebase/functions/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/grpc.js:87:24)
    at async GrpcClient.createStub (/MyProject/firebase/functions/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/grpc.js:212:23)
Caused by: Error
    at Firestore.getAll (/MyProject/firebase/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/index.js:784:23)
    at DocumentReference.get (/MyProject/firebase/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:201:32)
    at Function.run (/MyProject/firebase/functions/src/tracker.js:40:28)
    at wrapped (/MyProject/firebase/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions-test/lib/main.js:72:30)
    at Context.<anonymous> (/MyProject/firebase/functions/test/testTracker.js:42:26)
    at callFn (/MyProject/firebase/functions/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:366:21)
    at Test.Runnable.run (/MyProject/firebase/functions/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:354:5)
    at Runner.runTest (/MyProject/firebase/functions/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:677:10)
    at /MyProject/firebase/functions/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:801:12
    at next (/MyProject/firebase/functions/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:594:14)
    at /MyProject/firebase/functions/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:604:7
    at next (/MyProject/firebase/functions/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:486:14)
    at Immediate._onImmediate (/MyProject/firebase/functions/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:572:5)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're doing everything right, except I don't think you're initializing the `initializeApp` object correctly. Try this in your `index`:

```
admin.initializeApp({
  projectId: 'my-project',
  credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
});
```

You'll have to add a condition to use this version based on whether or not the environment variable is set though.

Comment: @JorisMans, does this answer your question?